# Maximal number of generators of first homology in Vietoris-Rips complex

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology, topological-data-analysis

For a point cloud $P$ with $n$ vertices is there a nice formula for the maximum number of points in a persistence diagram of the Vietoris-Rips complex on this point cloud?

Since in a VR complex a $1$-cycle must consist of $4$ distinct vertices at any filtration value of $\epsilon$ there should be $\binom{n}{4}$ cycles maximum. But of course this isn't actually true because if all sets of $4$ points make cycles then we will end up having to fill in many triangles as well.

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will likely be interested in the paper "Extremal Betti Numbers of Vietoris–Rips Complexes" by Michael Goff, from DCG in 2011: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-010-9274-z. See in particular Section 3 for results on 1-dimensional homology, although higher-dimensional homology is also considered.

A clarifying comment is that I suspect you are asking about Vietoris-Rips complexes of a point cloud $P$ embedded in some Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^d$. This is also the context considered in the Goff paper, and the dependence on $d$ is considered. One could also ask about Vietoris-Rips complexes of a point cloud $P$ embedded in an arbitrary metric space, which might be equivalent to asking what is the largest Betti number possible from an arbitrary clique simplicial complex with $n$ vertices.

While searching again for the above paper by Goff, I also ran across the following slides: https://plv.colorado.edu/dmoon/assets/docs/nzp.pdf

Best, Henry